# Add a link for a button

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hello i need to add a link in the following code to redirect the (submit button)
**Here the code**

```
<form class="checkout adq-billing" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo StaticAdqQuoteRequest::get_quote_list_link() ?>" method="post" name="checkout">
                <div class="col2-set">

            <?php 
                    //Billing/Account information
                    //, 'is_billing_filled' => $is_billing_filled
                    adq_get_template( 'adq-form-billing-details.php', array( 'checkout' => StaticAdqQuoteRequest::get_checkout() ) );
                    
                    ?>


                    <div class="col-2">
            
            <?php
                    //Force enabled to avoid core Woocommerce system
                    $shipping->enabled = StaticAdqQuoteRequest::is_shipping_enabled();
                    //Get Shipping options and address
                    $shipping->calculate_shipping( WC_Adq()->quote->get_shipping_packages() );
                    $packages = $shipping->get_packages();

                    if ( $shipping->enabled ) :

                        if ( get_option( 'adq_enable_shipping' ) == "user" ) : ?>
                            <label for="include-shipping-cost">
                                <?php _e( 'Would you want to include the shipping cost in quotation?', 'woocommerce-quotation' ); ?> <input id="include-shipping-cost" type="checkbox" name="include-shipping-cost" value="1" checked />
                            </label>
                        <?php endif;
                    
                        if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_ship_to_destination' ) != "billing_only" ) :
                            
                            adq_get_template( 'adq-form-shipping.php', array( 'checkout' => WC()->checkout() ) );
                                                 
                        endif;

                        echo '<div class="adq-shipping">';                     
                        foreach ( $packages as $i => $package ) {
                            $chosen_method = isset( WC()->session->chosen_shipping_methods[ $i ] ) ? WC()->session->chosen_shipping_methods[ $i ] : '';
                            adq_get_template( 'adq-cart-shipping.php', array( 'package' => $package, 'available_methods' => $package['rates'], 'show_package_details' => ( sizeof( $packages ) > 1 ), 'index' => $i, 'chosen_method' => $chosen_method ) );

                        };
                        echo '</div>';
                        
                    endif;
            ?>

                    <p id="quote_comments_field" class="form-row notes woocommerce-validated">
                            <label class="" for="order_comments"><?php echo __('Message','woocommerce-quotation') ?></label>
                            <textarea cols="5" rows="2" placeholder="<?php echo __('Please Any other requirements.','woocommerce-quotation') ?>" id="order_comments" class="input-text" name="order_comments" required></textarea>
                    </p>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <?php if ( wc_get_page_id( 'terms' ) > 0 && apply_filters( 'adq_checkout_show_terms', true ) ) : ?>
                        <p class="form-row terms">
                                <label for="terms" class="checkbox"><?php printf( __( 'I&rsquo;ve read and accept the <a href="%s" target="_blank">terms &amp; conditions</a>', 'woocommerce-quotation' ), esc_url( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'terms' ) ) ) ); ?></label>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" name="terms" <?php checked( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_terms_is_checked_default', isset( $_POST['terms'] ) ), true ); ?> id="terms" />
                        </p>
                <?php endif; ?>                    
                
                <input type="submit" data-value="<?php echo __('Submit Quote Request','woocommerce-quotation') ?>" value="<?php echo __('Submit','woocommerce-quotation') ?>" id="quote_place_order" name="adq_quote_place_order" class="button alt">  

                <a class="button wc-backward return-to-shop" href="http://localhost/test"><?php _e( 'Go Back', 'woocommerce-quotation' ) ?></a>

                    <input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce('woocommerce-process_checkout'); ?>">
            </form>
```

#############################################################
I have added a link and it works but the form was not submitted, is there's any way to submit a form with url redirection, view code

Answer (score 0):

The tag `<input type="submit" />` is used to submit a form.

You will find that this INPUT is inside a `<form action="">` tag. `action=""` is the path the form will be submit to.

If you don't need to submit the form, simply use a tag `<a></a>`.

```
<a href="#your-link.php" id="quote_place_order" name="adq_quote_place_order" class="button alt">
    <?php echo __('Submit','woocommerce-quotation') ?>
</a>
```

Comment: the link was redirected successfully but the form was not submitted! please view the full code

Comment: Of course, a tag `<a>` doesn't submit a form. to submit the form let `<input type="submit" />` and change the url in the tag: `<form action="your-url">`

Comment: Your first line, change the action `action="<?php echo StaticAdqQuoteRequest::get_quote_list_link() ?>"` by your url

Comment: thanks for your reply, could you please share me the code to copy and paste, because i tried and i didn't fix it!

Comment: Yes I can, what is the url you want to send to? Why do you want to change it?

Comment: After submitting the form, The current url of the plugin it redirect me to 404 page not found, also the form it doesn't display a successful message to inform user that the message was submitted,

Comment: i don't know how to show successful message after submitting the form, so i decide to redirect user to thank you page here the link: http://localhost/global/thank-you/  
If you can, show me how to put a succefully message after submit the form

Comment: here the plugin that i use, if you need to check it follow the link: https://woocommercequoteplugin.com/requestforquote/woocommerce-quotation-plugin/

Comment: are we still connected?

Comment: If you change the url, then you need to handle the form by yourself. You cannot change it where you are.  You are missing a page in your plugin, the thank you page. Check in the settings of the plugin, an option like `redirect when success`. The form is handled?

Comment: Exactly, there is no thank you page in the code and that's why I have to redirect the submit button to the custom page that I created. link: localhost/global/thank-you

Comment: Note: in plugin setting there's a option called (Custom URL to redirect after submitting a quote) but it is not working

Comment: You cannot change the submit button link. Because it is redirecting to the plugin to handle the form, and when the form is handled the plugin redirect to the 'thank you' page.

Comment: Go in the page you created your quote, and add your custom url there. If it is not working, this is an issue with the plugin. Try to reset your change in the code.

Comment: I've tested the live demo of the plugin and it works fine, and it show me the thank you page correctly: (YOUR QUOTE REQUEST HAS BEEN RECEIVED Thank you for your interest! Your quote request # is: Q.003027.)  but on my website not working!

Comment: I found the following code on the plugin : if ( ! empty( $_POST['adq_quote_place_order'] ) ) { //wp_safe_redirect( StaticAdqQuoteRequest::get_quote_list_link() );//exit; WC_Adq()->order->create_order();

Comment: when i hide the (//) it load the page and submit the form but it doesn't redirect me to thank you page

Comment: I've reset all changes and i have tested it after submitting the form it show this message: There has been a critical error on this website. also in my url it show /page_id=2203 but in demo of the plugin it show /quote-list

Comment: This is because you modified the code and created a FATAL ERROR my friend. Re-install everything without your changes.

Comment: I Re-install everything but i got the same problem, everything is works except the thank you page it display the same error (There has been a critical error on this website.)

Comment: Try to ask the dev team.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Form tag so you could add an `action` attribute to that. Now by clicking the submit button your form will be redirected to the URL that u assigned to the form.

```
<form action="site.com">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: not working for me, please view the full code